# Run Class method in parallel

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Task: i have a class that takes some arguments and runs a function in a cycle, that clones a  lot of git repositories. I'd like to run it in a parallel, but faced with errors such like

`cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object` (when trying multiprocessing)
`cannot pickle 'ConsoleThreadLocals' object` (when trying multiprocessing with dill)

Code structure:

```py
# main.py
import ProcessProjects

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ProcessProjects(
        project_list=['project1', 'project2'], 
        project_dir='projects', 
        repo_type='all',
        clear_before_start=True)
```

```py
# ProcessProjects.py
import git
import os
import re
import shutil
import params


class ProcessProjects:
    def __init__(self,
                 project_dir: str,
                 project_list: list[str] = ['all'],
                 repo_type: str = 'all',
                 clear_before_start: bool = False,):
        self.project_dir = project_dir
        self.project_list = project_list
        self.repo_type = repo_type
        self.clear_before_start = clear_before_start
        self.main()


    def _task(self, project_name):
        _data = params.projects[project_name]

        def _run(repo_type, repo_name, repo_branch, repo_url, repo_dir):
            repo = git.Repo.clone_from(repo_url, repo_dir)
            repo.git.checkout(repo_branch)

        def _get_inventory():
            _repo_url = _data['inventory']['url']
            _repo_name = re.findall(r'7999\/.+\/(.+)\.git', _repo_url)[0]
            _repo_dir = f"{self.project_dir}/{project_name}/inventory"
            _repo_branch = _data['inventory']['branch']
            if os.path.exists(_repo_dir) and os.path.isdir(_repo_dir):
                if self.clear_before_start:
                    shutil.rmtree(_repo_dir)
                    _run('inventory', _repo_name, _repo_branch, _repo_url, _repo_dir)
            else:
                _run('inventory', _repo_name, _repo_branch, _repo_url, _repo_dir)

        def _get_code():
            for _repo in _data['code']:
                _repo_url = _repo['url']
                _repo_name = re.findall(r'7999\/.+\/(.+)\.git', _repo_url)[0]
                _repo_dir = f"{self.project_dir}/{project_name}/code/{_repo_name}"
                _repo_branch = _repo['branch']
                if os.path.exists(_repo_dir) and os.path.isdir(_repo_dir):
                    if self.clear_before_start:
                        shutil.rmtree(_repo_dir)
                        _run('code', _repo_name, _repo_branch, _repo_url, _repo_dir)
                else:
                    _run('code', _repo_name, _repo_branch, _repo_url, _repo_dir)

        if self.project_list[0] == 'all' or project_name in self.project_list:
            if self.repo_type == 'all':
                _get_inventory()
                _get_code()
            elif self.repo_type == 'inventory':
                _get_inventory()
            elif self.repo_type == 'code':
                _get_code()

    def main(self):
        for project in params.projects.keys():
            self._task(project)
```

```py
# params.py example

projects = {
    'project1': {
        'inventory': {'branch': 'master', 'url': 'ssh://.../inventory.git'},
        'code': [
            {'branch': 'develop', 'url': 'ssh://.../code.git'},
        ]
    },
    'project2': {
        'inventory': {'branch': 'master', 'url': 'ssh://.../inventory.git'},
        'code': [
            {'branch': 'master', 'url': 'ssh://.../code.git'},
            {'branch': 'master', 'url': 'ssh://.../code2.git'},
        ]
    },
```

This is a code example without multiprocessing. When I call class, I specify, what projects I want to download, where to store it, and what type of repository i want to get.

How can I rewrite main method, to replace cycle

```py
for project in params.projects.keys():
            self._task(project)
```

and run task in a parallel?

for example

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool


with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(self._task, [project for project in params.projects.keys()])
```

TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
workers = []
for project in params.projects.keys():
    worker = Process(target=self._task, args=[project])
    worker.start()
    workers.append(worker)
for worker in workers:
    worker.join()
```

TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object

Comment: It seems that that happens because _task method uses self.vars, but i don't understand how to deal with it

Comment: I question whether you posted the actual code you tried. For one thing, the statement `with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:` will throw an exception since you have not imported `multiprocessing`; you imported `Pool` from that module so you would need just `with Pool() as pool:`. Also, in your comments you mention `self.vars`. I don't see where that is defined. You need to specify your platform (as a tag) and include actual source with multiprocessing along with a stack trace.

Comment: You are trying to launch Processes while still in the act of constructing an instance of ProcessProjects, since your constructor `__init__` calls `self.main`.  Processes need to pickle all the objects they work with, so this might cause a problem.  I'm not sure.  On general principles I think the main function belongs outside the constructor.